# SSRS date issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a query that is used in SSRS that reports summary and detail from a view in SQL Server 2008.  The problem I am having is that I cannot get the date range to calculate correctly.  This is the query:

```
declare @FromDate as Date

SELECT
    [ABS] =
    case when left(filename,2)='BA' then 'BAGS'
     when left(filename,2)='SX' then 'SOCKS'
     else 'APPAREL' end,
LEFT(filename,(charindex( '_', filename, charindex( '_', filename)+1)-1)) as [MATERIAL],
filename, 
CONVERT(varchar(50),delvd_dt,1) as DD,
fulfillment_type
FROM vw_Delivery_Log
WHERE(charindex( '_', filename, charindex( '_', filename)+1)-1)>0
AND delivered_to_ftp <> 6
AND fulfillment_type <> 'REDROP'
AND (convert(varchar(50),delvd_dt,1) > @FromDate );
```

I have the @FromDate variable as datetime as a variable in SSRS.  When I add a line at before the select statement "set @FromDate = '4/1/2013' the query produces the expected results, however without it the query produces no results.

I have also tried converting the @FromDate variable to date using a convert command as well as just entering text for the variable instead of selecting the date from the calendar.

I need to be able to look at smaller segments of the report due to sheer size of the dataset.  A month's worth of entries would be 250 pages of data.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wew, it may help if you clean up the query a bit, make it more readable for folks without context (us). There's a whole bunch of SQL irrelevant to the question you're asking, and several aliases (e.g. `delvd_dt`) that are hard to understand without racking your brain.

Comment: You said that "without" the `@FromDate` variable there are no results. What does "without" mean? Does it mean that you removed the complete condition from the `WHERE` clause, or that you passed `NULL` as the value, or something else? And can you post the absolute minimum query that shows the problem, e.g. `SELECT * from vw_Delivery_Log WHERE convert(varchar(50),delvd_dt,1) > @FromDate` or whatever?

Comment: the "@FromDate" is a variable on the report set as datetime.  By without "@FromDate" I mean that if I don't use the variable from the report, and set the value equal to something, I get the desired results.   So if I set the date for 5/1/2013 I will get today and yesterday's results.  I think that the ultimate question is this:  I have a varchar(50) in my database that I need to compare with a date time variable from the report to limit the result set.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't set the @FromDate it is NULL and the condition in the WHERE clause fails. if you want to be able to work with NULL @FromDate you need something like that:

```
AND (@FromDate IS NULL OR delvd_dt > @FromDate)
```